# WordPress Android App is Crashing When I Start App

Tags: android, json

I am trying to make an app for my WordPress website using json... the app debug successfully but not started it stopped working when i try to open app.. **Please Help**
Here is activity_main.xml File Please Check this out
**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Logcat File**

```
2019-11-22 08:33:19.368 2734-2734/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-22 08:33:19.369 2734-2734/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ats.sarkarijobs, PID: 2734
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ats.sarkarijobs/com.ats.sarkarijobs.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ats.sarkarijobs-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ats.sarkarijobs-3/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.ats.sarkarijobs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have added activity_main.xml and logcat file please check this out.

Comment: Share your logcat messages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174). Please also have a look into how to create a [mcve]. Posting your entire project is never really necessary.

Comment: @AnandJain I have added logcat file please check

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: @NovoLucas [Here is Code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am2ZDMYHLC-favTmQ59tpgxomus?e=x4Ylyw)

Comment: It'd be better if you post your XML here, instead of sharing the whole code. Share the part where you are using CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @NovoLucas Check Above Code i have added xml file by editing this Question

Comment: You need to add support design library to use CoordinatorLayout. Please add 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is AndroidX enabled, but you are not using AndroidX dependencies in your app level build.gradle. 
So, inside your project

1. Navigate to the `Refactor` menu
2. Click on `Migrate to AndroidX`

You might have to also make changes to your XML layouts-

Change `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` to `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`
and likewise CardView to `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Comment: Thank You so much Brother.. Now its working fine but there is one more problem i m faceing write now.. After running app the progress bar started and never gone and posts also not displayed on app .. please help

Comment: I'd suggest you look into the Android Logcat for any errors or messages. Do some digging as to what is causing it to happen.